# Error creating subsite after installing update

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

We used to be able to create subsites on our SharePoint 2013 server.  After installing the updates for April 2014, we started getting error below.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error: 
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>     Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.TemplatePickerUtil.GetFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior(LayoutsPageBase page, HtmlInputHidden featureDependencyErrorBehaviorHiddenInput) +116
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.NewSubwebPage.BtnCreateSubweb_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +759
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +145
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3585

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18447

==================================================================

Has anyone else had this problem?  Is there any way to solve it short of re-installing SharePoint and avoiding that update?

Comment: try to do iisreset

Comment: We did. It didn't work.

Comment: Have you applied a reboot after installing the SharePoint update?

Comment: Yes, we tried that. It still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

check Publishing Infrastructure Feature enabled under the site collection.

In case if required resetting the token for claim auth web app
reference:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14010583-ab45-4d53-ae34-af6d57b69d52/team-sites-can-only-be-created-by-farm-administrator-account?forum=sharepointadmin